# APK files, creating multiple copies

Tags: android

I wanted to have multiple copies of the same app on my Phone.
I have allready searched this forum and learned a lot!

After decompiling an .apk file, i can find and adapt the appname, but when i install the new copy it justs simply overwrites the old one.
I guess it has something to do with the 'directory' its installed to. So this is where i got stuck.

In currently use elesbb APK Tool & Notepad++

So if anyone wants to explain me (in n00bish words), Whats the most effective way?

Comment: I can't see a use case for this other than "I want to copy someone elses app"

Comment: I still want to stay and use the Original app, i just want to have multiple instances running.

Answer (score 0):

There´s a way to have multiple copies of your proyect, refactoring the package of your Android application, for example:
my original app "Iasi News" has the package :

```
com.jorgesys.news
```

to avoid my original app for overwriting i have to rename the package,

```
com.jorgesys.news2
```

and i change the name to "Iasi News v2"

Comment: Allright, when i open the Android Manifest i count 14 instances of the current package com.*original.app. Do i have to adapt them all?

Comment: yes unfortunately we have to change all the package references inside the manifest.xml, do a simple Replace.

Comment: Okay! I've adapted all the old packages and have adapted the name in the strings, but now when i try to install it simply says : "Not installed"

Comment: probably some original package names still inside your app.